# Need assistance using PHP to communicate with servers

Tags: php

I'm trying to help a client allow users to populate data from his website to another companies website. The website that has the servers is DialMyCalls and they have provided a PHP class to communicate with their servers. I am having trouble using that to actually communicate with them as I do not understand what fields I need to edit.

I have the API Key and another snippet of code to add contacts and I'm wondering if someone could walk me through what exactly needs to be done to make this code work.  Where do I place the "add contact" part of code to actually run this and see if it populates in the database.  I can provide any information you may need.

The following PHP class is from the [API provider](http://www.dialmycalls.com/api-docs/quickstart.php).

```
<?php
class RestRequest
{
protected $url;
protected $verb;
protected $requestBody;
protected $requestLength;
protected $apikey;
protected $acceptType;
var $responseBody;
protected $responseInfo;


public function __construct ($apikey = null) {

    $this->url              = null;
    $this->verb             = null;
    $this->requestBody      = null;
    $this->requestLength    = 0;
    $this->apikey           = $apikey;
    $this->acceptType       = 'application/json';
    $this->responseBody     = null;
    $this->responseInfo     = null;

}

public function flush ()
{
    $this->requestBody      = null;
    $this->requestLength        = 0;
    $this->verb             = 'POST';
    $this->responseBody     = null;
    $this->responseInfo     = null;
}

public function execute ($url = null, $verb = 'POST', $requestBody = null) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $this->url              = "https://www.dialmycalls.com/api".$url;
    $this->verb             = $verb;
    $this->requestBody      = $requestBody;
    try
    {
        switch (strtoupper($this->verb))
        {
            case 'POST':
                $this->doExecute($ch);
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException('Current verb (' . $this->verb . ') is an invalid REST verb.');
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidArgumentException $e)

    {           curl_close($ch);
        throw $e;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        curl_close($ch);
        throw $e;
    }

}
protected function doExecute (&$curlHandle) {
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $this->requestBody["apikey"] = $this->apikey;
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->requestBody);
//  curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: ' . $this->acceptType,'Expect:'));
    $this->responseBody = curl_exec($curlHandle);
    $this->responseInfo = curl_getinfo($curlHandle);
    curl_close($curlHandle);
}
}
?>
```

PHP Add Contact

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
$nums[] = array(
    "phone"=>"832201111".$i,
    "firstname"=>"just",
    "lastname"=>"testing",
);
}
$request->execute(
"/1-0/AddContact/",'POST',
array("names"=>json_encode($nums))
);
```

Comment: No. There is no personal client information given in my post.  All code can be found at the following url ( http://www.dialmycalls.com/api-docs/quickstart.php ).  Knowing that this code is all public information can you help provide a solution to my problem originally posted?  All help is welcome and I appreciate your concern of the code but I did post the link to their website in the original post.  EDIT: The original post did have an API Key but that is where I thought it MIGHT go, I have no idea. That API Key originally posted was mine for a free account I created, not clients

Comment: Removed downvote as it seems like it's legitimately sourced. Having said that, this is a bad question.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think much of the API - it's not very RESTful. Presumably an operation like [GetGroups](http://www.dialmycalls.com/api-docs/getgroups) should be idempotent, but that requires a `POST` operation, and in fact if you use the class with `GET`, it borks. Oh dear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a broad question, but the first thing comes to mind is that this file is a *library class*, and as such is not meant to be edited. You should include the file and instantiate an object in your own code.

Thus, download a fresh copy, and commit that to your version control in a suitable folder in the root of your project. Then, in your own code, do:

```
$rest = new RestRequest('yourkey');
```

From here, you can use the documentation to get this working. An understanding of HTTP and REST interfaces will be invaluable here, so it may be worth reading up first. It looks like the second snippet of code (to "add contact") might work - try that with your key, and examine the return results using `print_r`.

So, try this to add a contact to your list:

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) {
    $nums[] = array(
        "phone"=>"832201111".$i,
        "firstname"=>"just",
        "lastname"=>"testing",
    );
}

$request->execute(
    "/1-0/AddContact/",
    'POST',
    array("names"=>json_encode($nums))
);
```

You can then examine the output thus:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($request->responseBody, true) . '</pre>;
```

Unfortunately the [docs don't detail return parameters](http://www.dialmycalls.com/api-docs/addcontact) so you might have to use trial-and-error to determine whether the call succeeded - hopefully it *is* actually returned! As I mentioned earlier, the remote service doesn't seem to respect the basic principles of REST - if you like, you could ask them why read-only operations don't use `GET`, and saves don't use `PUT` (their supplied class throws an exception if you don't use `POST`).

You should request a new key, since you appear to have posted your existing key, which should be secret information. With this key, other people could post using the privileges afforded to your account, and in general you don't want this to happen.

Comment: Thank you Halfer for your response.  The key originally posted was for a free trial account I created about 30 minutes ago and is not clients information.  I will still be sure to request a new key.  I will be sure to read up on REST and follow your instructions to get this going.  Thanks again for a good response.

Comment: No probs. I've added your example, how to examine the return result, and some notes on the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the updates.  I am beginning to wrap my head around how this works.  I have added the DialMyCallsAPI.php file (unedited) to the server. In my own php file I have started with the first snipet of code you gave me for adding my key, from there I have posted the second portion of the code (add contact) below that.  I am currently receiving an error on line 13 `code$request->execute( `  I will continue to research the issue.  Thanks again for being so helpful, much appreciated.

Comment: ^ What's the error, exactly?

Comment: @Matt: The other bit of advice is, always develop locally - copy stuff to your server when you are confident it is working.